# Sharepoint Social tagging with web service - private tags

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010

We want to handle tags of SharePoint users with web service.

It is possible with the functions of the SocialDataService.asmx. We can select the tags of the user with the GetTagTermsOfUser function, but this function returns only with the user's public tags.

The program what uses the web service runs with the permissions of the user.

Can I select the user's private tags? How?